# could not find implicit value for parameter semigroupal

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I just tried to compile the following code:

```
import cats.Monoid
import cats.instances.boolean._ // for Monoid
import cats.instances.int._ // for Monoid
import cats.instances.list._ // for Monoid
import cats.instances.string._ // for Monoid
import cats.syntax.apply._ // for imapN
import cats.syntax.semigroup._

case class Cat2(name: String, yearOfBirth: Int, favoriteFoods: List[String])

object FancyFunctor {

  val tupleToCat: (String, Int, List[String]) => Cat2 =
    Cat2.apply _

  val catToTuple: Cat2 => (String, Int, List[String]) =
    cat => (cat.name, cat.yearOfBirth, cat.favoriteFoods)

  implicit val catMonoid: Monoid[Cat2] = (
    Monoid[String],
    Monoid[Int],
    Monoid[List[String]]
  ).imapN(tupleToCat)(catToTuple)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val garfield = Cat2("Garfield", 1978, List("Lasagne"))
    val heathcliff = Cat2("Heathcliff", 1988, List("Junk Food"))

    val a = garfield |+| heathcliff

  }

}
```

And I've got the error message:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/developer/Desktop/scala/catssemigroupal/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/scala/catssemigroupal/src/main/scala/io/khinkali/FancyFunctor.scala:25:22: could not find implicit value for parameter semigroupal: cats.Semigroupal[cats.kernel.Monoid]
[error]   ).imapN(tupleToCat)(catToTuple)
[error]                      ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Feb 24, 2018, 10:18:01 PM
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This compiles with cats 1.0.1:

```
import cats.Monoid
import cats.instances.boolean._ // for Monoid
import cats.instances.int._ // for Monoid
import cats.instances.list._ // for Monoid
import cats.instances.string._ // for Monoid
import cats.syntax.apply._ // for imapN
import cats.syntax.semigroup._ // for |+|
import cats.instances.invariant._ // for  catsSemigroupalForMonoid: InvariantSemigroupal[Monoid] 

object FancyFunctor {

  /*
  val tupleToCat: (String, Int, List[String]) => Cat2 =
    Cat2.apply _

  val catToTuple: Cat2 => (String, Int, List[String]) =
    cat => (cat.name, cat.yearOfBirth, cat.favoriteFoods)

  */

  case class Cat2(name: String, yearOfBirth: Int, favoriteFoods: List[String])
  implicit val catMonoid: Monoid[Cat2] = (
    Monoid[String],
    Monoid[Int],
    Monoid[List[String]]
  ).imapN(Cat2.apply)(c => Cat2.unapply(c).get)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val garfield = Cat2("Garfield", 1978, List("Lasagne"))
    val heathcliff = Cat2("Heathcliff", 1988, List("Junk Food"))

    val a = garfield |+| heathcliff

  }

}
```

How to find quickly using nothing but a browser (without IDE):

- Search for `Semigroupal` (the missing typeclass) in the [Doc](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/instances/package$$invariant$.html?search=Semigroupal)
- Search for `Monoid` using text-search of the browser *on the result page*
- Click on the implicit method that returns `Semigroupal[Monoid]`,
- Follow the links to the defining class: [InvariantMonoidalInstances](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/instances/InvariantMonoidalInstances.html)
- Look for linear subclasses, pick something more precise than "all"

Hint: the overkill-approach `cats.implicits._` works on your code.

---

As a bonus: you don't have to redefine `Cat2.apply` and `Cat2.unapply`, they are automatically provided for every `case`-class.

Answer (score 2):

I also got a bit puzzled by this problem when reading the book (and what an amazing book it is!). Two things helped me realize that I needed the Invariant type class coming from `import cats.instances.invariant._`:

1) The text above the code says

> For example, we can combine Monoids using Invariant

And yet there is no invariant visible in scope!

2) If you click on the `imapN` method you will see that it takes two implicit parameters `implicit invariant: Invariant[F], semigroupal: Semigroupal[F]`

These two things combined make you look for a way to add Invariant in scope. And since throughout the book the prevalent way of doing this is to get them from `cats.instances...` that's what I did. Hope it makes sense.